# Power BI - Create a slicer on multiple True/False flag columns

Tags: powerbi, slicers

Let's say I have I have a table of businesses and a business categories:

```
Business | Agricultural | Commercial | Industrial
--------------------------------------------------
Company1 |       0      |      0     |      1
Company2 |       1      |      0     |      0
Company3 |       0      |      1     |      0
```

Instead of a category column, I have a column for each category and 0 or 1 as a true/false value. What would be the best way to make a slicer in Power BI for these values? The slicer options would then just be the headers of these columns.

Also, my actual table is hundreds of columns and millions of rows, so some solutions are probably out of the question (transpose, unpivot, etc.).

Comment: The correct solution is to unpivot the table. Number of columns and rows is irrelevant, because the data structure must be correct (currently it's not). Besides, Power BI can handle billions of records, and unpivoting shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you, good to know. I've had Power BI run out of memory many times so I guess I didn't have enough faith in my computer. But this worked perfectly, should have tried it first.